# How to consume a WCF Service with external MVC 3 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I have created a simple WCF Service for purpose of displaying a table details. My service is ready.

Now in my external MVC 3 Application i need to consume my WCF Service. So i have done *Add Service Reference*.

How can i write the proxy code in my MVC 3 app to consume my service?
I am new to WCF and ASP.NET MVC ..what should i do next to consume wcf service?

My Code:

*Interface*

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBooksService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetBooksInfo(int BookId);
}
```

*Class*

```
public class BooksService:IBooksService
{
    public string GetBooksInfo(int BookId)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "myDB";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_BooksInfo", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BookId", BookId));
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
            return dr[0].ToString();
        else
            return "-1";
    }
}
```

In mvc 3 app, i added service reference.

Comment: start with something as simple as [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+consume+a+WCF+Service+in+MVC+3+Application%3F&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Yasser i have gone through those, but seems like they are little intermediate level which is apart from my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to generate a proxy for the service and then call methods on that proxy. For simple cases the following code should be more than enough or you can use it as a starting point anyway:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(//url for the service goes here);
_proxy = ChannelFactory<ImplementedInterface>.CreateChannel(binding, endpointAddress);
```

Please note that this does not even require adding the service reference (as long as you have a copy of the interface implemented by the service) and it will give you a proxy that you can use like any other class in your project.  Just make sure to catch wcf faults (FaultException, FaultException, TimeoutException, CommunicationException) and not the usual .Net ones when you call methods on the generated proxy.

Comment: If he's added this as a service reference then he wouldn't need to do this as it would get set in the `web.config`

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I realise that, however I was trying to provide a generic solution that is easy to implement for someone who is new to both wcf and mvc and that would work even if adding a service reference is not an option.

Comment: @JTMon Thank you, i have understood this way.the other way, i.e now i have taken an MVC 3 empty web app and added service reference. in this case, what is my next step to do? I mean anything like i need to add controller, write code etc..because this is an empty mvc web app and i just added service reference. after that not getting how to proceed..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you want to make a `using` reference to your WCF Service in your controller to whatever name you set when you added it to your application. So if you called it `WCFService` and your project was called `MyMvcApplication` you'd so something like this: `using MyMvcApplication.WCFService`

Then you'd instantiate that with the name of your service class in your controller, so if your `.svc` class was called `ServiceClass` you'd do something like this: `ServiceClass myService = new ServiceClass();`

Then in your Actions/Methods you'd simply call the methods you created on your `ServiceClass` like so: `myService.MyMethod(myParam);`

### Edit

In your controller you'd have something like:

```
using MyMvcApplication.WCFService

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private BooksServiceClient myService = new BooksServiceClient();

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var book = myService.GetBooksInfo(id);

        return View(book);
    }
}
```

Does this not work then? As your code looks fine...

If this doesn't work then I suggest looking at the new `ASP.NET Web API` as that will replace WCF in the future and is far easier to implement and make call's too..

Comment: i am getting IService and ServiceClient in my intellisense, not getting service class